# Ejecutar una aplicacion local Web PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

Sucede que he hecho un sistema en PHP , este sistema funciona a través de consultas a una BD creada en MySQL.
He utilizado WAMP para la instalacion del servidor que me provea las funcionalidades que requiero, PHP, MySQL, Apache.

La duda surge al querer transportar el sistema completo a otra maquina que carezca de todo lo que necesita para funcionar, he escuchado hablar de instaladores pero desconozco si me seran de utilidad y en caso de que asi sea, ¿como los podrìa utilizar?, ya que necesito

1.-Instalar WAMP server

2.-Crear la BD en MySQL

3.-Copiar una carpeta (la de mi sistema) a la carpeta localhost

4.-Crear un acceso directo a localhost/misistema/ en el escritorio para acceder al sistema

5.-Crear un icono en el menú inicio que inicie WAMP y acceda al sistema automáticamente.

Answer (score 1):

todo sistema que tenga PHP con MYSQL debe tener un config.php, revisa los parametros de ese config.php que coincidan con el acceso a la BD nueva

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes acceso a la computadora donde deseas montar el sistema y no tienes problema en descargar wamp para mi seria la opcion mas sencilla.

1. Instalar WAMP
2. Exportas la BD de donde la tienes actualmente y la importas en la nueva maquina, con phpmyadmin por ejemplo.
3. Copias toda tu carpeta con los archivos necesarios a la nueva carpeta localhost, no olvides actualizar tu usuario y contraseña en caso de no ser la misma para tu conexion a la BD en tu archivo PHP.
4. Lo que mencionas de crear un acceso directo.

Answer (score 0):

Si la otra computadora esta dentro de tu red, puedes configurar el WAMP para que accedan a tu aplicación por la ip o puedes utilizar Noip o en ultimas subir la aplicación a uno de los muchos hosting gratuitos que soportan php y mysql para que quede en la web...